# Arel Deprecation Warning when running rake db:create

Tags: activerecord, windows-7, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mysql2, active-relation

I'm trying to create an app in Rails 3.1 with mysql2 v 0.2.6.  When running `rake db:create`, I get the following error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Arel::Visitors::VISITORS is deprecated and will be removed. 
Database adatpers should define a visitor_for method which returns the appropriate 
visitor for the database. For example, MysqlAdapter.visitor_for(pool) returns 
Arel::Visitors::MySQL.new(pool). (called from mon_synchronize at 
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201)
```

I can access the MySQL monitor, so the gem appears to be installed correctly.  What else could be going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your msql gem.

In ./Gemfile

```
gem require 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.6'
```

bundle update mysql2

Comment: So this version of mysql2 does not want to install correctly...'failed to build native extension' and all that jazz.  But 0.2.6 installed fine?

Answer (score 0):

use the below specified version in gemfile.

```
gem 'mysql2', '~>0.3.10'
```

then run

```
bundle install
```